# Does SharePoint Search support range tags?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a project to digitize approximately 1 million images for which metadata will be added to facilitate search.

Each image is, for example, a page in a dictionary. But not text. Just a static scanned image. OCR is not an option :(

My objective is to emulate the current search procedure which consists of looking up the alphabetical entries till the correct page is found. In absence of machine readable text, I am looking at tagging each page with Dictionary range tag. For Example (Apple-Canada). So if someone searches for "Banana", it should hit the (Apple-Canada) range Tag.

Is this supported in SharePoint out of the box? If not, is there an addon product which provides this functionality or am I looking at building a customized extension?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why isn't OCR an option? SharePoint can OCR some images (e.g. TIF and JPG) out of the box! And there are more IFilter (which make documents searchable and does OCR) vendors than you can throw your stick at.

Comment: I'm coming into the project late. We don't have the flexibility to change the SOW at this stage. Just trying to salvage what we can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the IFilter for TIF files is done with a couple of clicks and gives you free OCR along the way. Very good for scanned pages.

On your question though: No, SharePoint does not have any kind of "range" tags or fields. The only vaguely similar thing to what you are requesting is the Thesaurus of the search. There you could define acronyms and synonyms for words and it would actually search for something else. So you could enter Banana but it would actually search for Apple. Some examples here: [How to: Customize the Thesaurus in SharePoint Search and Search Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2008/09/23/how-to-customize-the-thesaurus-in-sharepoint-search-and-search-server.aspx).

Other than that I can only think of a custom implemented search provider giving you the flexibility you need.